# Mapbox not available on firebase using react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, mapbox-gl

I am using react to build a web page that contains a map component - using mapbox-gl.

The app runs fine on localhost but when I deployed it to google firebase, the map is just a black square.

(In both cases the markers on the maps works fine)

I tried to downgrade mapbox-gl version to 1.13.0 - didn't word eighter.

Can anyone please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded to v5.2.11 of react-map-gl using:

yarn upgrade react-map-gl@5.2.11
and it works.

but found a few more options here :  https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/issues/1266